# Notice: Undefined variable: conn and Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, variables, undefined, fatal-error

Hi All I get these two errors when trying to post to my database

Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptuts\sandbox\blog\admin\index.php on line 17

Here is the code;

```
    > <?php 
    require '../functions.php';
    require '../db.php';
    $data = array();


    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' )  {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];

        if ( empty($title) || empty($body) ) {
            $data['status'] = 'Please fill out both inputs';
        } else {
            Blog\DB\query(
                "INSERT INTO posts(title, body) VALUES(:title, :body)",
                array('title' => $title, 'body' => $body), 
                $conn); // line 17
        }
    }

view('admin/create', $data);
```

and here is the second one

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs    \phptuts\sandbox\blog\db.php on line 26

```
function query($query, $bindings, $conn)
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query); //line 26
    return $stmt->execute($bindings);

}
```

Hoping someone can help me with this as I was doing the php fundamentals course on tutsplus The Obligatory Blog: Part 4 found here https://tutsplus.com/lesson/the-obligatory-blog-part-4/

update here is the db.php file

```
<?php namespace Blog\DB;  

$config = array(
    'username' => 'root', 
    'password' => 'foobar',
    'database' => 'blog'
);

function connect($config)
{
    try {
        $conn = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $config['database'],
                    $config['username'],
                    $config['password']);
        $conn->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        return $conn;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}

function query($query, $bindings, $conn)
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($bindings);

    return ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) ? $stmt : false;

}

function get($tableName, $conn, $limit = 10)
{
    try {
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM $tableName ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit");

        return ( $result->rowCount() > 0 )
            ? $result
            : false;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}


function get_by_id($id, $conn)
{
    $query = query(
        'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1',
        array('id' => $id),
        $conn
    );

    if ( $query ) return $query->fetchAll();
    // else
}
```

Comment: Post the content of `../db.php` and make sure you remove any sensitive data such as password, username and ip. The reason its not working is very likely you missed a step on the tutorial and/or you changed the name of something as it is giving the undefined index error on $conn so it is related to your database connection. [**Click here to update your question with more information**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18499952/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Jo should create the db connection first. and store it in `$conn`.
The second error is related to the first. As there is no connection, `$conn` is `NULL`, and so has no member functions. Any.

As for your code:

```
<?php 
    require '../functions.php';
    require '../db.php';
    $data = array();

    $conn = Blog\DB\connect($config); //this does not work actually. but mainly the connection was missing.


    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' )  {
...
```

Comment: you never call connect;

Comment: I tried to add $conn = connect($config); but got error Fatal error: Call to undefined function connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptuts\sandbox\blog\admin\index.php on line 6

Comment: ok. Try the edited version... My bad.. missed the namespace declaration :S

Comment: It wont let me vote up but I had to add   $conn = connect($config); to my db.php file!! Thank you sooooo much took me two days to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `$conn` is not a database instance.

Make sure that `$conn` actually holds a connection to the database. You can check this with

```
var_dump($conn)
```

Comment: I attached my db.php file to see if you can see were I went wrong